# Can not save/update entity using JPA in spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA in my application, and it works once I query for objects, however it throw error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available` once I tried to save or update an object.

This is the java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:dao.properties")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        .....................
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", ...........)

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com....");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Note I use `proxyTargetClass = true` in the  `@EnableTransactionManagement`, since I do not want to create the useless interfaces in my application.

And this is the concrete implemention of the dao:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public abstract class AbstractJPADao<I, E> {
    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<E> type;
    public AbstractJPADao() {
        type=....
    }

    @Override
    public Result<E> find(I id) {
        E e = entityManager.find(type, id);
        return Result.newInstance().setContent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Result<E> find(Map<String, Object> condition) {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(".......));
        return Result.newInstance().setContent(q.getResultList());
    }

    @Override
    public E save(E element) {
        entityManager.persist(element);
        return element;
    }
    @Override
    public E update(E element) {
        entityManager.merge(element);
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(E element) {
        entityManager.remove(element);
    }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class DepartmentDao extends AbstractJPADao<String, Department> {
    @Override
    protected String selectCause(Map<String, Object> condition) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And the controller as the client of the dao:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/deps")
public class DepartmentCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Result create(@Valid Department department, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            departmentDao.save(department);
            return Result.newInstance().setContent(department);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("...");
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong?

---

dao.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proj
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
#hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Why are there two annotations `@Autowired` and `@PersistenceContext`
over the `protected` field of type `EntityManager` in `AbstractJPADao`?

Comment: `EntityManager` is provided in the `JpaConfig` as a bean which should be injected to the `AbstractJPADao`.

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: Don't know if this is your issue, but another similar problem was solved by using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` instead of  the `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation.

Comment: I am using tomcat at the moment, and I prefer to use the standard annotation.

Comment: How does your `persistence.xml` look like? Also the `dao.properties` could help. I suspect the root cause may be possible to find somewhere in there.

Comment: There is no `persistence.xml`, all the entity are registered by annotation. And the I have update the post to add the `dao.properties`.

Answer (score 4):

Try renaming method `transactionManager` to `txManager` in the class `JpaConfig`

*Autowiring* goes by the name *txManager*

***Edit***

Also the framework could be expecting a no argument method for txManager. Can you try changing to

```
 @Bean
 public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
     JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
     transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
     return transactionManager;
 }
```

Comment: @hguser Edited my answer. Could you please try?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried: remove the arguments in the method, and use both 'transactionManager' and 'txManager` as the method name. None of them work. :(

Comment: @hguser so far everything was just guess work from my side. I am going to try myself a sample some time today. If no one answer your question before my experiments, I'll post my findings here to help you solve this.

Comment: Thanks, looking for your experiments.

Comment: BTW, I have update my prototype project to `bitbucket`, if you have an account, I can invitation to you to fork the project.

Comment: Please do. my id: gipsy

Comment: Done, you may have received the notification.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed Tiny, you have two annotations @Autowired and @PersistenceContext over the protected field of type EntityManager in AbstractJPADao.
Try removing @Autowired. @PersistenceContext is enough to inject the EntityManager.